# Preciso contar os números primos até um determinado numero n

Tags: python, funções, if, while, return

Escreva a função n_primos que recebe como argumento um número inteiro maior ou igual a 2 como parâmetro e devolve a quantidade de números primos que existem entre 2 e n (incluindo 2 e, se for o caso, n).

```
def n_primos(x):
começo = 1
divisivel = 0
naodiv = 0
while começo <= x: 
    fator = 2 
    if começo % fator == 0: 
        divisivel += 1  
    else:
        naodiv += 1  
    começo += 1
    fator += 1
return naodiv
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Alguém me ajuda por favor :(

Comment: A duplicada sugerida acima diz como obter os números primos, mas não é difícil adaptar as respostas existentes para computar também a quantidade, já que a maior dificuldade parece ser o algoritmo para determinar se o número é primo, e isso já é coberto pelas respostas

Answer (score -1):

manow eu não entendi sua lógica para contar os números primos que são números divisíveis somente por eles mesmos e 1. Porém para te ajudar, vc está toda hora atribuindo valor ao "naodiv" toda vez que o número é impar, já que vc o "fator" sempre vai está valendo 2. A última linha dentro do 'while' (fator += 1) não tem efeito nenhum, já que toda vez que o loop acontece o "fator" receberá o valor 2.
Ver se isso te ajuda.